# HTML / CSS: I'm Experiecing With Divs?

Tags: html, css

Code: http://pastebin.com/00nds6kn

I am seeking to put all of this on one page, as in there is no scrollbar present on the browser when on that page. I have attempted to set the heights of the divs as a percentage via CSS but was unsuccessful.

I am also unable to remove the small white gap from between the div "footer" and div "banner" containing the image.

```css
body {
            width: 100%;
            margin: 0px;
            background-color: #F5F5F5;
        }
       
        #container {
            height: 100%;
        }
 
        #navigation{
            color: white;
            background-color: #292526;
            width: 100%;
            position: fixed;
            top: 0px;
            padding: 0.5% 0.5%;
        }
       
        #navigationLeft {
            width: 24.5%;
            display: inline-block;
            vertical-align: middle;
            font-size: 180%;
        }
 
        #navigationRight {
            width: 74.5%;
            display: inline-block;
            vertical-align: middle;
        }
       
        #navigation ul{
            float: right;
        }
       
        #navigation ul li {
            display: inline;
        }
 
        #navigation a {
            font-size: 120%;
            color: white;
            text-decoration: none;
        }
       
        #footer{
            color: white;
            background-color: #292526;
            width: 100%;
            padding: 0.5% 0.5%;
        }
```

```html
    <div id="container">
   
        <div id="navigation">
            <div id="navigationLeft">
                <a href="#">Visit Clare Ireland</a>
            </div><div id="navigationRight">
                <ul>    
                  <li><a href="#">Home |</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Maps |</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Hotels |</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Appartments |</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Attractions |</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Essentials |</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Bars and Clubs |</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Transport</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
       
        <div id="banner">
            <img src="http://i.imgur.com/VsIRZNZ.jpg" alt="The Cliffs Of Moher"/>
        </div>
       
        <div id="footer">
            <p>Placeholder</p>
        </div>
       
    </div>
```

Comment: can you copy and paste your code into your question, indenting it as appropriate or clicking the button to recognise it as code. Cheers

Comment: Please rephrase your post as a question to guide you instead of a request for others to solve your problem.

Comment: For those who are vote down fans I should inform that it maybe is right to vote down a bad question but keep in mind that your negative votes will make the asker unable to ask any more questions

Answer (score 1):

To remove the blank space above footer add this to your `#banner` element:

```
line-height: 0;
```

To remove the scrollbars add this to your css:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 0 !important
}
```

**EDIT**

To have the whole page fit within the viewport of the browser you can calculate the needed height of the `banner` since the `footer` and `navigation` elements have fixed heights:

```
height: calc(100vh - 133px);
```

The above gives the element 100% the height of the viewport, minus the combined height of the `navigation` and `footer` elements (approx 68.5px + 64.5px ~ 133px).

You can also remove the `position: fixed` to your `navigation` element since it will always be visible anyways.

View a demo of this [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/88bwazw5/)

Comment: Thank you, I was able to remove the blank space. What I mean by removing the scrollbar is that I want the web page to fit on the browser without needing to scroll down or across. I attempted to do this with "height" but I couldn't get it to work properly.

Comment: Ah okay. Try [this](https://jsfiddle.net/88bwazw5/)

Comment: +1 for use of line-height and calc(). Do you think `body { overflow: hidden; }` would be better for hiding the scrollbar? I don't like using webkit specific attributes when (I think) plain standard CSS will do. Also I generally avoid `!important`.

Comment: @CodingWithSpike I think OP wants to make the whole site to fit within viewport. My first answer for hiding scrollbar was for hiding it while still being able to scroll. `overflow: hidden` removes this possibility.